# Can only ping through access point, no browsing

Tags: networking, internet, ping

I'm using a Pi with a 3G dongle, and sharing the internet connection with the connected LAN-devices. That's working well.

Now I want to add an access point to the network; a standalone device as I need the better antennas. When I'm connected to the WiFi, I can `ping` and `traceroute` servers on the internet, but I can not access any websites.

I tried to access the internet with multiple computers and I replaced the access point with another brand. Same problem.

Any ideas what's wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Can you `ping 8.8.8.8` and `ping google.com`?

Comment: It's definitely important to see if you can ping a DNS name (`google.com`). Most likely, your DNS configuration is messed up. What error do you get while trying to access a website?

Comment: I can't ping google.com, only 8.8.8.8. So i set the DNS manually to 8.8.8.8 and internet works! Changed the ISC-DHCP settings and the DNS is working now proberly. Thanks!